# Recommended way of accessing BASE_DIR in Django

Tags: python, django

I am coding an automated menu module in Django that will list all the packages in BASE_DIR that have a urls.py file. For this I obviously need to access BASE_DIR, but I haven't been able to find a standard way of doing this. I could just do:

```
from myproject import settings

do_stuff(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

but I'd rather not hardcode it to myproject since this menu module could also be used for other applications. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This isn't a question about BASE_DIR, but about importing settings. Your proposed solution is not valid Python in any case: imports don't use file paths like that.

The standard and fully documented way of importing settings in Django is this:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

This will always work, in any Django project, and will allow you to access any of the settings.

Comment: Just to be fair, it literally is a question about BASE_DIR. It's just the *answer* involves importing settings. Which the OP obviously realized, but just was confused about.

Answer (score 2):

For example, in a views.py file, we can do the following to use the value of BASE_DIR

```
from django.conf import settings
value = settings.BASE_DIR
```